# Average and synchronize a timeseries with varying timestamps to a user-defined interval in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, time, time-series, average, synchronize

Assume the following timeseries (ts) with assigned values:

```
time    val
15:00   4
15:45   7
17:12   2.3
17:50   2.9
```

Every value from a timestamp is valid until the next appears. Thus, from 15:00 to 15:45 the value is 4 or from 15:45 to 17:12 it is 2.3. Every new data point between these timestamps should have the same value. What i want is a new ts, with a constant time-interval and a pre-defined start point. Let's say the starting point is 15:00 and the interval should be 30 min. Normally, I could use the synchronize function - however, the function uses the interpolation method and this is not what i need here, since the values between the data points should not be interpolated, but be averaged if timestamps are overlapping.

The new ts should be like:

```
time   val
15:00  4
15:30  5.5
16:00  7
16:30  7
17:00  4.18
```

The value for timestamp 15:30 is computed as = (4*15+7*15)/30, and so on. I have implemented a code, that is capable of fixing this by applying the trapz function with a lot of if statements. However, I was wondering if there are better/simpler solutions around, as a modified synchronize function, since I have more than 500.000 data points.

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you are doing the average, it's almost the same as doing interpolation (its actually linear interpolation). Your average for 16:00 and 16:30 are both 7, how does this work?

Comment: True, but not in case of the other timestamps that are within a timestamp (e.g. the new timestamp 16:00 which originates from the 15:45 timestamp). The value 16:00 is valid from 16:00 to 16:30 and the value from 16:30 is valid until 17:00. From the original data set, the value obtained for this period is 7 (from the 15:45 time stamp that is valid until 17:12)

Comment: I think in that case you want to round to the nearest time stamp before interpolation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I want to use something like resample(ts1,'15:00':'0:30':'17:00') or synchronize(ts1,ts2) where ts2 includes ['15:00':'0:30':'17:00'], but I don't know how to properly modify the interpretation method to consider my conditions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by dividing all time steps into minute-values and afterwards applying the trapezoidal rule to get the sum of the area under the curve (AUC) and then the average by dividing with the applied minute interval.

```
    AllValues = interp1(Time,Data,NewTime,'previous')';
    [Xdata,Ydata] = stairs(NewTime,AllValues);
    NewTS = timeseries(Xdata,Ydata);
    TrapzSum =  cumtrapz(NewTS.time,NewTS.data);
    TrapzSum =  TrapzSum(1:2:end); 
    NewResults = diff(TrapzSum(IndicesOfNewInterval))/MinInt;
```

Comment: Thanks for proposing the edit on my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10892141 - Your edit was correct but the reason why it got rejected (I didn't reject it) was because your comment made it sound like you were editing it unnecessarily.  In your comments regarding the changes,  you need to be more explicit.  **Point** to the documentation and explain **why** you had to change it from 0.90 to 90 and 0.99 to 99... because that's what it is **supposed** to be instead of the mistake I had in the past: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html. Thanks either way!

Comment: Cool! Thanks for pointing it out, I will remember that for the next time and I thought the OP of the answer had to accept/reject it. Actually, I first tried to comment on your answer, so you could make the change (but I wasn't allowed, since of my low stackoverflow status). Conversely, I was allowed to propose an edit for the answer...

Comment: Edits go to a review queue where Stack Overflow users review the edit you made to determine the legitimacy of the edit.  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10892141 - Your comments on the edit weren't clear enough as to why the edit was warranted which is why it got rejected.  In any case, you're a relatively new user so you will certainly get enough reputation to eventually make comments :) Welcome and again thanks for the edit. I've made the change myself even though your edit was rejected.